# java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.BLOB cannot be cast to oracle.sql.BLOB

Tags: java, oracle, blob

I have problem retrieving a blob object from oracle DB to java API with jdbc.
The problem is when I execute a Collable statement with a function from the db which return me a blob field this exception is thrown on the line :

`tempBlob = (oracle.sql.BLOB)cstmt.getObject(1);`

with this error message :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.BLOB cannot be cast to oracle.sql.BLOB.
```

The object which I get from the DB is a instance of `oracle.sql.BLOB`. The tempBlob
variable is a object `oracle.sql.BLOB`. Where is the problem?

Comment: Could be a classloader issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two oracle jar files may be in your classpath. Please remove one jar and deploy again.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime one JAR is in the application classpath and another is in the application *server* classpath (eg.: in Tomcat `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`)

Answer (score 0):

Dont Cast again like:

```
BLOB tempBlob = (oracle.sql.BLOB)cstmt.getObject(1);
```

Solution :

```
OutputStream outstrm =(rs.getBlob(1)).setBinaryStream(1L);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while generating a jasper report.

I replaced the `class=oracle.jdbc.OracleBlob`
with `class=java.sql.Blob` in the jrxml file of that report. It worked for me.