# Unable to persist null into oracle BLOB using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g, blob, openjpa

I am trying to persist image `Byte[]` and scheduler `TimerHandle` to oracle 11g database using JPA (EclipseLink 2.3.x)

When the value of the property is not null, JPA was able to persist Byte[]/TimerHandle to database, but when those property is `null`, it then gives this exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.BLOB incompatible with oracle.sql.BLOB
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setBlob(OraclePreparedStatement.java:6663)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setBlob(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:128)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setBlob(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:387)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.LoggingConnectionDecorator$LoggingConnection$LoggingPreparedStatement.setBlob(LoggingConnectionDecorator.java:1499)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setBlob(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:387)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary.setNull(OracleDictionary.java:633)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.setTyped(DBDictionary.java:1285)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.RowImpl.flush(RowImpl.java:896)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.RowImpl.flush(RowImpl.java:856)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.batchOrExecuteRow(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:99)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(BatchingPreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.persistence.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushAndUpdate(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flushInternal(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:100)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.PreparedStatementManagerImpl.flush(PreparedStatementManagerImpl.java:88)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:550)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.ConstraintUpdateManager.flush(ConstraintUpdateManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.flush(BatchingConstraintUpdateManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:105)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.AbstractUpdateManager.flush(AbstractUpdateManager.java:78)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.flush(JDBCStoreManager.java:737)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.flush(DelegatingStoreManager.java:131)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2178)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2076)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1847)
    ... 70 more
```

How can I fix this problem so that `null` can be persisted to database as (null) in database?

Comment: Oddly enough, it's saying that the problem is a `ClassCastException`.  It's saying that the same class is incompatible with itself!?

Comment: @user919860 Yes, [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411306/java-lang-classcastexception-oracle-sql-blob-cannot-be-cast-to-oracle-sql-blob) suggested the same class appeared twice at the class path, one offered by server classpath and one offered by yourself. But that should cause the problem to always exist, not only to null. And I did check classpath and didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution... 
Use plain oracle.sql.BLOB instead of any other classes mapped to BLOB when having this problem.

```
@Entity
public class FileStorage implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long fileId;
    @Lob
    //private byte[] fileData; replaced this line with the line below.
    private oracle.sql.BLOB fileData;
    //Getter and setter
}

public class WorkingClass{
    private EntityManager em;
    public foo(){
        FileStorage f = new FileStorage();
        f.setFileData(BLOB.getEmptyBLOB());
        //f.getFileData().setBytes(someByteArrayData);
        em.persist(f);
    }
}

public class ErrorClass{
    private EntityManager em;
    public foo(){
        FileStorage f = new FileStorage();
        f.setFileData();
        //fail when the line below is commented
        //f.setFileData(someByteArrayData);
        em.persist(f);
    }
}
```

But now problem plagued `TimerHandle`. After manual serialization and deserialization using `ObjectOutputStream`/`ObjectInputStream`, the timer seems not serializing correctly, resulting in `NoSuchObjectLocalException` when I called `((TimerHandle) o).getTimer()` even I confirmed the timer is still running (Calling a @Timeout method that constantly output a message).