# Unable to retrieve Bfile data

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have problem retrieving a bfile object from oracle DB to java API with jdbc. The problem is when I execute a Prepared statement with a function from the db which return me a bfile field this exception is thrown on the line :

BFILE temp = (oracle.sql.BFILE )cstmt.getObject(1);

with this error message :

java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.BFILE cannot be cast to oracle.sql.BFILE . 
The object which I get from the DB is a instance of oracle.sql.BFILE . The temp variable is a object oracle.sql.BFILE . Where is the problem?

Comment: see if this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411306/java-lang-classcastexception-oracle-sql-blob-cannot-be-cast-to-oracle-sql-blob

Comment: it looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411306/java-lang-classcastexception-oracle-sql-blob-cannot-be-cast-to-oracle-sql-blob

Comment: Are you executing this code inside an application server? It looks like an ojdbc library classpath conflict, do you have an ojdbc library both in application server lib and in your webapp WEB-INF\lib? Can you show your classpath?

Comment: Sorry my suggestion was outdated

Answer (score 1):

Two ojdbc library files may be in your classpath. Please remove one jar from `JBOSS/server/<configuration>/lib`, or `JBOSS/lib` or webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` and try again.

Comment: I am getting same error. I had removed one jar from application server.